# SSRS 2008 export to MS Word with dynamic Page Footer

Tags: ms-word, ssrs-2008

I have a requirement to have a page footer show up on the first page of a report, and then no page footer on subsequent pages.

When I create a report that toggles the visibility of objects in the footer it works fine in BIDS, and when I export to PDF, however upon export to MS Word, the footer from the first page appears on every page.

In other tests I have attempted, it appears that other than the Page Number, anything that appears on the first page of a report's footer, will appear on every page when exported to Word.

Does anyone have ideas for how to create Footer content that changes depending on what page you are on, and will persist through the export to MS Word?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is pretty late in coming to this user, but for any others fighting with this, please see the msdn SQL Server export to Word write-up here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627455(v=SQL.100).aspx
```

In a nutshell, toggling states anywhere in the report is not supported.  Whatever the state of the report item is on the first page is what it'll be throughout the exported report.  With that in mind, it appears that PDF will be a better format to support with your customers.